# Retreiving data in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have three text files as http://paste.debian.net/plain/1027720. As the third file is in the following format

```
Third File

salesID | custID | prodID | itemCount
1|1|1|3
2|2|2|3
```

I want to display the table such that custID    should  be  replaced    by  the customer    name    and the prodID  by  the product description,
as  follows:
1: ["John" "shoes" "3"]
What I did till now is :

```
(def data (slurp "cust.txt"))
(->> (for [line (clojure.string/split data #"[ ]*[\r\n]+[ ]*")]
       (-> line (clojure.string/split #"\|") rest vec))
     (map vector (rest (range))))
```

How I can retreive and map the values accordingly?

### EDIT

```
"demo_1.txt"
content id|name|address|phone-number
1|John|123 Street|456-4567
2|Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567

"demo_2.txt"
prodID | item | Cost
1|shoes|14.96
2|milk|1.98
```

Comment: So where do the customer and product ID's come from?

Comment: There are two text files that consists of customer id and its description and another file containing product id and its description. @Bob Jarvis

Comment: First File. "demo_1.txt" content

id|name|address|phone-number

eg:

1|John|123 Street|456-4567
2|Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567

Second File. "demo_2.txt" content

prodID | item | Cost
eg:

1|shoes|14.96
2|milk|1.98

Comment: When adding information to a question please don't put it in a comment; instead, edit your question add the information directly to the body of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The processing of this data is similar to how I process CSV files. I like to split the problem into functions that do line to vector and vector to map, using the first row as the header for each.

```
(defn line->vec [s]
  (s/split s #"\|"))

(defn vec->map [desc row]
  (into {}
    (map vector desc row))) ; Map accepts multiple collections

(defn file->maps [filename]
  ; Destructuring here, for easy capturing of header row
  (let [[desc & lines] (->> (slurp filename)
                            (s/split-lines)
                            (map line->vec))
        desc-keys (map keyword desc)]
    (for [line lines]
      (vec->map desc-keys line))))
```

For your demo files, you can use `group-by` to generate a map, sort of like an index (I manually fixed the header formatting, but you'd want to do it with a utility fn):

For `(group-by :content-id (file->maps "demo_1.txt"))`

```
{"1" [{:address "123 Street",
       :phone-number "456-4567",
       :name "John",
       :content-id "1"}],
 "2" [{:address "123 Here Street",
       :phone-number "456-4567",
       :name "Smith",
       :content-id "2"}]}
```

For `(group-by :prodID (file->maps "demo_2.txt"))`

```
{"1" [{:item "shoes", :prodID "1", :cost "14.96"}],
 "2" [{:item "milk", :prodID "2", :cost "1.98"}]}
```

And then replace each column with its index value:

```
(defn replace-value [index idx-key m k]
  (update m k #(get-in index [% 0 idx-key])))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [customers (group-by :content-id (file->maps "demo1.txt"))
        products (group-by :prodID (file->maps "demo2.txt"))]
    ; Use customers and products to replace some data
    (->> (file->maps "demo_3.txt")
         (map #(replace-value customers :name % :content-id))
         (map #(replace-value products :item % :prodID)))))
```

And the result:

```
({:prodID "shoes", :content-id "John", :salesID "1", :itemCount "3"}
 {:prodID "milk", :content-id "Smith", :salesID "2", :itemCount "3"})
```

Then it should be straightforward to convert those maps back into the format you want.